# Riddle - Where am I hiding?

Tags: riddle, visual

I was approached by a mate who wanted a riddle to use on his prospective girlfriend on a date to ask her to be his girlfriend.

```
You can find me 
Where the water trickles
And the water spouts
Between where the sound would be heard
You will find the third
which is the middle
Least covered by green
But not maroon
Open to air
```

Here's an image for some tips (Hint's because people may not be from Brisbane, Aus).

> The lake has a fountain in the middle
>
> The building in the middle, toward the left pathway is a waterfall
>
> [image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: The text in green is 'Roma Street Parkland'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is located at

> the Middle of the Open Air Theatre

The reasoning is as follows: 
Where the water trickles

> Water trickles from an **open** tap (artificial one) or from an almost drying up fountain (natural one) - that means "open" is the first word

And the water spouts

> Water spouts at a standpost (aritifical one) or from a fountain (can be natural / artificial one) into **air**, giving the second word as "air"

Between where the sound would be heard

> Sound could be heard in an **"theatre"**, usually a clearer sound giving this word as the third word of the location.

The next 4 lines are direct reference / clues to the location of the structure:
which is the middle

> The middle of the theatre

Least covered by green

> There is no greenery in the theatre, as we can see

But not maroon

> Eliminating the non-green objects/structures..here includes is not maroon

Open to air

> Is open and clearly seen ...